# Distribute content to different lists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 different lists (ul). Each time a user clicks a link, I want some content to be added to one of the lists with the least content.
Suppose these are the lists:

```
<ul id="column1" class="column">
<li></li><li></li>
</ul>
<ul id="column2" class="column">
<li></li><li></li>
</ul>
<ul id="column3" class="column">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

when the user clicks on the link, some content should be added to the 3rd list. (`#column3`). How can I achive this? Thanks.

**PS:**
It will be better if the content (say content.php) loads with a *loading* message. Meaning:

Before:

```
<li>Loading...</li>
```

After

```
<li>....CONTENT.....</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what came to my mind:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
   var columns = $('.column');
   columns.sort(function(a, b) { 
      return $(a).children('li').length - $(b).children('li').length;
   });
   $('<li>Loading...</li>').appendTo($(columns).first()).load('content.php');
});
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ48U/1/)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Just one question. I want to append the content from another file. How can I do that? I previously loaded content using `load` function: `$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())` but I want to use the `append` fucntion.

Answer (score 2):

This feels hackish but I can't think of a cleaner way:

```
$('#clicker').click(function(){
   var smallList;
   var smallest = 1000;
   $('ul').each(function(){
       var curLength = $("> li", this).length;
       if(smallest > curLength ){
          smallest = curLength;
          smallList = this;
       }
   });
   //add content to smallList
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5HZ4W/

If you have two `ul`s with the same number of children the first one will be used.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Just one question. I want to append the content from another file. How can I do that? I previously loaded content using `load` function: `$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())` but I want to use the `append` fucntion.

Answer (score 0):

```
//declare a function for the JavaScript `sort()` function
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

//add event handler to the click of all `a` elements
$('a').on('click', function () {

    //setup array of `ul` elements and then another array of the number of children each has
    var cols = [$('#column1').children('li'), $('#column2').children('li'), $('#column3').children('li')],
        arr  = [cols[0].length, cols[1].length, cols[2].length];

    //sort the array with the number of children numerically
    arr.sort(sortNumber);

    //iterate through the `ul` elements until the the first one that has the lowest number of children is found
    for (i in cols) {
        if (cols[i].length == arr[0]) {

            //append a new `li` element to the `ul` element with the fewest children
            cols[i].parent().append('<li>hola</li>');        
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/AcadK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
// HTML //
<ul id="column1" class="column">
    <li>item</li><li>item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="column2" class="column">
    <li>item</li><li>item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="column3" class="column">
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="button">Click to add</a>

// JS //
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var num = 1000;
            var $list;
            $('.column').each(function(){
                if ($('li', this).length < num){
                $list = $(this);
                num = $('li', this).length;
            }
            });

            $list.append('<li>item</li>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7rRQs/2/

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. All of these work. Although I changed the `$('ul')` to `$('.column')` to prevent using other `ul`s in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, firstly you should verify the LIs length on the lists. Or you can make a counter that will loop through the lists index and then you append the new LI.

```
var App = {
    lists: ['#column1', '#column2', '#column3'],
    index: 0,
    getList: function () {
        if (this.index == this.lists.length + 1) { // verifying if it's in the last column index
            this.index = 0;
            return App.lists[0]; 
        } else { 
            return App.lists[this.index++]; 
        } 
    }
}; // global configs    
$("#myLink").bind('click', function () {
    var $li = $(App.getList()).append('<li></li>');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getLastLalala.php',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $li.text('Loading...');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $li.html(data);
        }
    });
});
```